# Angular Data Binding problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So I want the user coming to my portfolio to enter their first name on the index.html page. Then I will welcome the user on the welcome page. How do I pass the information from the index.html to the welcome.html. I'm a novice at angular, your will be very grateful!

**index.html:**

```
<header ng-controller="UserName as myApp">
    <form >
        <label><h1>Enter Your First Name: </h1></label> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="clients" autofocus />
        <button><a href="welcome.html">CLICKME</a></button>
    </form>
    <h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
</header>
```

**welcome.html:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="propic"></div>
        <div class="blurb">sfdvsdfvsdv <span ng-controller="FirstCtrl">{{data.message}}</span> fsdv sdfvsdfv sdf  fs vsdfv sdfvf f vsdfv sdfv sfdv dsv fdv</div>
    </div>
```

**app.js:**

```
(function(){
  var myApp  = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('UserName', function(){
    this.product = name;
  });

  var User = {
    name: ""
  }

});
```

Here is the github: https://github.com/wiafe/Portfolio

And here is the page: http://wiafe.github.io/Portfolio/

PS: The h1 that's being bind in index.html can be ignored I was just testing something.

Comment: you have to bind user to $scope. I'm not sure angular is good framework for portfolio I think is much easier to do that with jQuery also there is more potential problems.

Comment: @CzłowiekFinŚpiewak Can you point me in the direction of how to do it with jQuery?

Comment: Sure.

You can save input value to localstorage in index.html then print this value
from localstorage in welcome.html http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: I believe your fundamentally not understanding the concept of a single page application (SPA). I'd recommend looking into [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), and [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) for starters and understanding that you should not be directing the user to another html page.

Comment: @KirillFuchs I'm not making a single page application though.

Comment: Thats why you don't need angular.

Comment: @user3922686 Then for your simple use case angular brings little value to the table and you just need to look into local storage, or cookies.

Comment: @CzłowiekFinŚpiewak Ah I see your points. So if it isn't a single page app, don't use AngularJS. Thank you!  Where you pointed me to is very helpful.